# jQuery images preload callback in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing script for lightbox gallery. I want to user prelaod techique for elegant image loading. My current script is:

```
for (var i in imgs) {
    var tmp_thumb=$('img');
    tmp_thumb.on('load', function(){
        O.SG.thumbs.append('<li><a style="background-image:url(\'' + imgs[i].thumb + '\')"></a></li>');
        $(this.)remove();
    }).attr('src', imgs[i].thumb);
}
```

The problem is, when `load` callback is called, loop counter `i` has almost always the last value from `img` array.

How to pass to callback the proper value of `i` from the context of lode

Answer (score -1):

The problem is nothing stops your loop, you are setting a bunch of callbacks and by the time they begin getting called, the value of i has hit the end.  Try using deferreds.  There are examples online.  Here's a pretty decent one:  http://aboutcode.net/2013/01/09/load-images-with-jquery-deferred.html